# mac osx development environment

Tags: c, macos, unix

i have a unix c programming assignment in which i do some advanced C network programming.this is my first step into advance programming. so i was wondering what is the best combination of tools for this on a mac. using an IDE like Eclipse is how i'd normally do it but i have to make my own makefiles and stuff. so i would like to learn how it can be done effectively using may be emacs or vim + other tools. it will be quite a big project so i am worried about project management and debugging issues mostly as well as the productivity factor. in essence i want to learn how programmers do it in the professional environment without the bloated IDE part. i am using Snow Leopard.i would also delve into C++ and python in the future so may be something that will be useful for those as well.

Comment: For the most part, getting to grips with Makefiles would be your best friend and to be comfortable on the command line. Google for makefile tutorials, pull down an already existing copy of a Makefile. Use that as the basis to do the edit-compile-debug cycle. Once you are comfortable with that, use the Gnu auto-tools chain (automake, autoconf).

Comment: Makefiles, seriously? He asked about Mac OS X, not HPUX. XCode people, XCode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you're asking for how to do it with makefiles/VI/etc. but on the Mac, Xcode is really the way to go, especially for large projects.  It's a very effective wrapper that will call gcc and gdb  and the linker for you.  Especially when moving to a new platform, not having to worry with many of the pesky details will be a big leap in productivity.  It's IDE debugger is quite awesome.

Of course you can also use makefiles etc.  Many projects (just to take OpenSSL as an example) come with makefiles and you can compile them on the Mac from the commandline just like under the *ix operating systems, i.e. calling ./configure and then make.  But setting up stuff like that (e.g. compiler options for universal binaries and such) is tedious  while  the IDE it's just a few options.  Also, if you google for specific questions, you will find far more answers on how to do it with Xcode.

If you want to get started with Xcode, it's either on your Mac operating system CD (it just does not pre-install automatically) or you can download it from Apple.  When you run it, just open a Mac OS X Project of type "Application - Commandline Tool" and you'll have a project with a main.c set up in a minute.  You can then just run it or run it in the debugger like that and adding more source files to it is rather easy.

Xcode can be quite a beast for setting up an already large project (we ported a large project with DLLs and depending exes (overall 250000 lines of code) to the Mac and just getting that all set up wasn't what you call a piece of cake) but if you start from scratch you'll easily grow into it.

Bottom line is that Xcode certainly is equipped to deal with large projects and I can not imagine a more productive way of doing it (I have used hand written makefiles and such in the past so I know both worlds).

Comment: yes i reckon xcode is the tool to use in a mac but my concern is wudn't it be better to learn a tool that i can use in a linux box as well in cases i may have to test it under linux. thats my only concern otherwise i wud definitely go for xcode.

Comment: @sfactor: you're interested in learning OS X development, not Linux development, right? I'm sorry to say, but each new platform brings new challenges, and one of the (essentially) required challenges for developers moving to OS X is to learn XCode. Don't sell yourself short: just learn it, embrace it, and love it. You'll be very happy you did!

Comment: @sfactor: Well, as I said, the Unix way of doing things works on the Mac too.  When you install Xcode you'll get gcc and friends installed which are required to compile/link from the command line. 

Another interesting point maybe.  If you compile a program in Xcode (a sample program for example) you can have a look at how Xcode calls the compiler (in the Build pane you can watch all the tools running by and there is a button to see their details), so you can borrow the parameters for compiler and linker from there.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode is your friend. It's free and is a very nice IDE. When you launch XCode, just start a new Console application (it'll be ANSI C).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

If learning the rudiments of unix editors, shell programming, make, etc., are part of the assignment, then you just need to dive in and learn what you need to learn. Some good books will help. Obviously you need K&R. I always liked the O'Reilly books for Unix stuff, usually because they are the thinnest. I hate thick computer books because they never get read. You should also learn how to use the man pages.

Vim vs. Emacs is a religious choice. If you ask any Unix guy what is the best, he will invariably tell you the one he learned first, because chances are he never learned the other. In my case, I've been using Vim so long that my escape key is worn out and the commands are hard-wired into my brain. Obviously, I think it's way better than emacs (which I never learned!) If you are lucky enough to have a Mac as a work station, install mac vim. It's great.

Make is complicated enough so that you will never really master it. Just learn enough to compile and link your program. You can always learn more if you need it.

Version control is an interesting question... I use RCS for small stuff. Like vi, it is on every Unix machine. For really big projects, I use subversion, but like editors, most people use whatever they learned first. Git people will say its the only one to use, etc.

Command line debuggers are a pain, which is a main selling point for Xcode. I've used gdb, but I don't remember it as a pleasant experience. Its been so long since I used it, I can't even remember how to start it up. There must be better debuggers by now. Try google.

Bottom line, all the things you mentioned are big topics. You need to take realistic bites of each and not get tangled in the weeds. It can take years to master them all.

Finally, I'd stay as far away from C++ as possible! Objective C is much better. Personal prejudice!